Generating a conjugate representation of an irreducible self-conjugate representation of $S_n$
Suppose we have a complex matrix representation $\Gamma_{ij}^\sigma \in \mathbb{C}^{d \times d}$ of dimension $d$ for the permutations $\sigma$ of the group $S_n$ of permutations of $n$ objects.
Suppose further that this representation unitary, irreducible, and self-conjugate.
There should therefore be a unitary transformation $U_{ij} \in \mathbb{C}^{d \times d}$ such that $U\Gamma^\sigma = \text{sign}\left(\sigma\right) \Gamma^\sigma U$ where $\text{sign}\left(\sigma\right)$ is $+1$ and $-1$ for even and odd permutations, respectively.
Is there a systematic way of generating a $U_{ij}$ satisfying this equation? Is the solution unique within an overall complex phase?
As perhaps the simplest possible example, we can take the complex functions $x, y$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$, i.e. $x(X,Y):=X$ and $y\left(X,Y\right):=Y$ which form a unitary, irreducible, self-conjugate representation of the permutation group $S_3$.
The action of a permutation $\sigma \in S_3$ is defined on a function $f$ by $O_\sigma f(X,Y):=f(X',Y')$ where $X'$ $Y'$ a coordinates of the point $X,Y$ after application of the equivalent $D_3\cong S_3$ point group operation of the equilateral triangle.
The Hilbert space on which the group acts is the set of square-integrable complex functions on $\mathbb{R}^2$.
It is not difficult to see that the change of basis $x \to y$, $y \to -x$ results in a matrix representation conjugate to the original.
However already at $S_4$ the complexity is too great and I can't work out the transformations by inspection/guess-and-check.

There is probably a nice explicit description of this using the natural basis of irreps of $S_n$, but I don't see it immediately. The map $U$ is unique up to scaling however, given two choices, their difference $U_1U_2^{-1}$ is a $G$ endomorphism, so is a scalar by schurs lemma.

First we need to clarify some terminology: typically (I think) "self-conjugate" means a complex representation $V$ which is isomorphic to its dual $V^{\ast}$, or equivalently to its complex conjugate $\overline{V}$ (which is the same representation as $V$ but with scalar multiplication twisted by complex conjugation). For representations of finite groups this condition is equivalent to the character $\chi_V$ being real, and every irreducible representation of $S_n$ has this property (because they are all real, and even rational).
But this is not what you mean; what you mean is a representation $V$ of $S_n$ which is isomorphic to the tensor $V \otimes \text{sgn}$ of $V$ with the sign representation. This condition is equivalent to the character $\chi_V$ vanishing on odd permutations, and if $V$ is irreducible it happens iff the partition corresponding to $V$ is self-conjugate, which I assume is where you get this terminology from.
So, here is a systematic although possibly unsatisfying procedure for answering the general question: if $V, W$ are two isomorphic irreducible representations of a finite group $G$ (e.g. you've computed that they have the same character), how does one write down an isomorphism between them? The answer is that $\text{Hom}_G(V, W)$ is the $G$-invariant subspace of the internal hom $[V, W] \cong V^{\ast} \otimes W$, and the projection onto this $G$-invariant subspace is given by averaging over $G$:
$$[V, W] \ni F(-) \mapsto \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} g F(g^{-1}(-)) \in \text{Hom}_G(V, W).$$
So if you pick a "sufficiently generic" initial choice of $F \in [V, W]$ (which is just some linear map $V \to W$, or more explicitly some matrix), e.g. literally choose its matrix entries randomly, then this projection is nonzero and gives a nonzero $G$-invariant map $V \to W$, which if $V, W$ are irreducible is necessarily an isomorphism. If $V, W$ are unitary representations this map is necessarily unitary up to scale so can be made unitary by scaling it appropriately.
